# Adding TSParticles params in React Particle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-particles-js

I am trying to replicate ts particle params to use in React particles. I used the same params what are working in tsparticles, But in React it is not getting displayed.
Here are the below config params for both TsParticle and React Particle.

TSParticles

```
particles: {
    number: { value: 10, density: { enable: true, value_area: 9999999 } },
    color: { value: "#ffffff" },
    shape: {
      type: "square",
      stroke: { width: 0, color: "#000000" },
      image: { src: "img/github.svg", width: 50, height: 50 }
    },
    opacity: {
      value: 1,
      random: true,
      anim: { enable: true, speed: 1, opacity_min: 0, sync: false }
    },
    size: {
      value: 3,
      random: true,
      anim: { enable: false, speed: 4, size_min: 0.3, sync: false }
    },
    line_linked: {
      enable: false,
      distance: 150,
      color: "#ffffff",
      opacity: 0.4,
      width: 1
    },
    move: {
      enable: true,
      speed: 0.5,
      direction: "bottom-right",
      random: true,
      straight: false,
      out_mode: "out",
      bounce: false,
      attract: { enable: false, rotateX: 600, rotateY: 600 }
    }
  },
  interactivity: {
    detect_on: "canvas",
    events: {
      resize: true
    },
    modes: {
      grab: { distance: 191.80819180819182, line_linked: { opacity: 1 } },
      bubble: { distance: 250, size: 0, duration: 2, opacity: 0, speed: 3 },
      repulse: { distance: 695.3046953046953, duration: 0.4 },
      push: { particles_nb: 4 },
      remove: { particles_nb: 2 }
    }
  },
```

React Particles

```
particles: {
      number: { value: 10, density: { enable: true, value_area: 99999 } },
      color: { value: "#ffffff" },
      shape: {
        type: "square",
        stroke: { width: 0, color: "#000000" },
        image: { src: "img/github.svg", width: 50, height: 50 }
      },
      opacity: {
        value: 1,
        random: true,
        anim: { enable: true, speed: 1, opacity_min: 0, sync: false }
      },
      size: {
        value: 3,
        random: true,
        anim: { enable: false, speed: 4, size_min: 0.3, sync: false }
      },
      move: {
        enable: true,
        speed: 0.5,
        direction: "top-left",
        random: true,
        straight: false,
        out_mode: "out",
        bounce: false,
        attract: { enable: false, rotateX: 600, rotateY: 600 }
      },
      interactivity: {
        detect_on: "canvas",
        events: {
          resize: true
        }
      },
    },
```

Link for both TsParticles and React Particles

[TSParticle](https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/oNXMadW)

[React Particle](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-waterfall-p3rob?file=/src/ParticleComponent.js)

Comment: In the CodeSandbox sample you are using an old version of `react-particles-js`, `tsparticles` is a dependency starting from 3.x version of `react-particles-js`. If you want to be sure you can use `react-tsparticles` with the same `tsparticles` version

Comment: @Caelan You have example for using tsparticles in react ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tsparticles-dw43f https://github.com/tsparticles/react-landing-page-template https://github.com/tsparticles/react-auth-template These are some samples